# How to visualize open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for different distances.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $O=(0,0)$, $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ be two points on the plane. I am being asked to find the closure and the interior of some subsets of the plane like a line or $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ on the topology associated to the following distances:

$$D(P,Q)=
\begin{cases}
0, \quad &\mathrm{if} \ P=Q\\
d(O,P)+d(O,Q), &\mathrm{otherwise} \
\end{cases}$$
where $d(P,Q)$ stands for the euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R^2}$,

$$\delta (P,Q)=
\begin{cases}
d(P,Q), & \mathrm{if}\ O, P, Q \ \mathrm{are \ aligned}\\
d(O,P)+d(O,Q), & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\rho(P,Q)=
\begin{cases}
|y_1-y_2|, &\mathrm{if} \ x_1=x_1\\
|y_1| + |x_1-x_2|+|y_2|, &\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Now, the trouble I'm finding is in visualizing how exactly are the open balls $B_D(A,r)$, $B_{\delta}(A,r)$ and $B_{\rho}(A,r)$ for some point $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$, so I need some help with that in lrder to start finding the closure and the interior of subsets of the plane.

For now, I've only been able to note that if $P=0$, then the first two metrics are the euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the case where $P\neq 0$ seems out of my reach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $D(P,Q) \leq d(P,Q)$ for starters. If I'm not wrong then $D(P,Q) = \delta (P,Q)$ for all P, Q. If OPQ are on one line then $D(P,Q) = d(P,Q)$. Did you try to visualise this using some grid?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk Sorry but how is $D(P,Q)\leq d(P,Q)$? Take $P=(1,0)$ and $Q=(2,0)$. Then $d(P,Q)=1$ but $D(P,Q)=2$,so...  And yes, I tried to do some drawing, but I ended up with some point lying outside of what I thought it was the open ball.

Comment: My bad I meant it the exactly the other way around. It's the triangle inequality.